# Override private method

Tags: java, overriding

I am reading "Thinking in Java" and have a doubt. In the chapter "reusing classes", section "final and private", it says that a private method cannot be overridden. However, I tried it on the machine. It actually could be overridden.

Here is the code:

```
class Amphibian {
     private void print() { System.out.println("in Amphibian"); }
}

public class Frog extends Amphibian {
     public void print() { System.out.println("in Frog"); }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Frog f = new Frog();
          f.print();
     }
}
```

That prints:

> in Frog

Comment: Your code doesn't actually compile.

Comment: It compiles on my machine.

Comment: Then the code "on your machine" isn't identical to the code in your question, because that code is glaringly broken.

Comment: I have nominated this question for reopening. The question it was (somehow) marked as a duplicate of is a completely different question... I'm not sure how 5 people managed to agree this was a duplicate of that.

Comment: @JasonC welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: @Goldname thanks, i'm new here.

Answer (score 12):

You didn't *override* it, you just *hid* it with a new method with the same name.

If you didn't create a new `print()` method, your `Frog` class wouldn't have one.

Comment: exactly, use the `@Override` annotation, you will get an error :)

Comment: ok. Thanks. So without @override, it is just hide the definition instead of overriding it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `@Override` will check if you are actually overriding an inherited method. If you are making a typo or if there isn't any method you are overriding, it will flag that as an error

Comment: Frog.java:4: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override void print() { 
    ^
1 error

Comment: I got a little confused again by looking at the example above. It seems that with and without override have no big difference except that it require you to override instead of to overload the method.

Comment: @NoviceCai: The `@Override` annotation is just a marker to make it clearer that you are trying to override something. It doesn't change the code in any way.

Comment: Try calling `super.print()` from `Frog.print`. You'll find you can't. Also, try calling `print` from some other method on `Amphibian`, and you'll find that Amphibian method always calls `Amphibian.print`, never `Frog.print`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks.  The private method is not seen from derived class. So it does not make sense to override a private method.

Comment: While many books and probably the spec call this method hiding, it seems odd to call it so: private methods aren't accessible in child classes, so can you really hide what's already hidden? But for answering exam questions, yes, this is method hiding.

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate the difference between overriding and hiding, consider this:

```
class Amphibian {
    private void print() { System.out.println("in Amphibian"); }
    public void callPrint() {
        /* 
         * This will DIRECTLY call Amphibian.print(), regardless of whether the
         * current object is an instance of Amphibian or Frog, and whether the
         * latter hides the method or not.
         */
        print(); // this call is bound early
    }
}

class Frog extends Amphibian {
    public void print() { System.out.println("in Frog"); }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frog f = new Frog();
        f.callPrint(); // => in Amphibian

        // this call is bound late
        f.print(); // => in Frog
    }
}
```

The "overriding" (i.e. hiding) method doesn't get called, the one in the parent class does. Which means it's not really an override.

Comment: this is a little trick here. If you make print in Amphibian private, you cannot override it. However, if you make it public, no matter whether you put @Override, it will always get overridden in Frog.

Comment: I tried your code by make private to public, and put or not put @Override in front of print in Frog. I got the same result.

Comment: @NoviceCai There's no trick involved, that's how Java works. `@Override` doesn't change the semantics of the code, it merely makes the Java compiler give you an error if the annotated method isn't overriding anything. The point of the annotation is to catch errors, not to make a method override one in the base class. Any *virtual* method can and will be overriden by another method with a compatible signature in a child class. IIRC, in Java, every non-`private` method is virtual, regardless of how any other method in the hierarchy is annotated.

Comment: @NoviceCai When I change `private void print()` to `public void print()` in the above sample, the output changes to "in Frog", so I'm not sure how you're getting "the same result". (Unless you're changing the method in `Frog` which is missing the point.)

Comment: @NoviceCai For further reading you might look into "virtual method tables" (which is how overriding is implemented in Java), and the concepts of "late binding" and "early binding". The explanation why my code sample behaves how it does is because `print()` in `callPrint()` is bound *early* to the *nonvirtual* implementation of `Ambhibian.print()`. If you change `Amphibian.print()` to `public`, it becomes a *virtual* method, and will therefore be bound *late*, which means an overriding implementation will be called if there is any in the current instance.

Comment: what i mean is that no matter you put @Override not not, it will  print "in Frog".

Comment: @NoviceCai Well, no. Because that's not what `@Override` does, and I don't know why you would assume it would. As I said, it **does not** change the behaviour of Java code, it just enables a compiler warning/error, as the very brief documentation for the annotation says: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a `private` method in `subclass` but it will not be overridden. But it still follows access modifier rules which are used in overriding

If you make wider `access modifier`(default, protected, public) in `superclass` method when `subclass's` method is private  then compiler shows errors. It follows overriding rule but doesn't override actually.